# Wait between starting background processes in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a master script that is scheduled via cron job , The master script would need to call two child scripts parallelly but with a wait time in between  (let's say 2 minutes )

below is how the master looks like. How can i add wait time between child 1 and child 2, such that child 2 starts after 1 min though child 1 script is still not finished. Right now i am adding desired wait time in child 2 as workaround but there are several such master that would run both the childs with different wait times hence its tedious to everytime edit child 2 .

```
#!bin/bash
echo "start both the script"
sh child1.sh  & sh child2.sh
echo "child 1 & child 2 finished"
sh child3.sh
echo "child 3 finished"
```

what i tried so far , but unfortunately this waits for child 1 to finish then sleeps 2 min and starts child 2 . Any suggestions ?

```
 #!bin/bash
    echo "start both the script"
    sh child1.sh  && sleep 2m && sh child2.sh
    echo "child 1 & child 2 finished"
    sh child3.sh
    echo "child 3 finished"
```

Comment: `sh child1.sh & sleep 2m; sh child2.sh &`

Comment: But don't use `sh` if you want `bash` (like you tagged for). `/bin/sh` only promises you a POSIX-compliant shell, *not* the full bash language. It's much better to use `./child1 & sleep 2m; ./child2` (after renaming your scripts to take out the `sh` extension, and making sure they have proper shebangs and the execute bit set) -- that way the script can choose its own interpreter, rather than having the interpreter forced to be `sh` and the shebang ignored (even if it asks for `#!/usr/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/ksh` or whatever else).

Comment: ...see http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/ for an essay by @erlkonig re: why using `.sh` (or other) extensions on scripts leads to trouble down the road. See also http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/.sh for timestamped history of the `!.sh` factoid in the freenode #bash IRC channel, to demonstrate that this has been established consensus on what constitutes good practices for over a decade. And see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Choose_Your_Shell for guidance on selecting between `sh`, `bash` and other options.

Comment: The shebang lines should be `#!/bin/sh` if you use `sh` — it should normally be an absolute path name after the `#!`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - thank for the answer that worked as I expected !!!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - thank you for additional info and documentation links. i changed my script   `#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "start both the script"
  ./child1 & sleep 10s; ./child2
echo "child 1 & child 2 finished"
sleep 1m
./child3
echo "child 3 finished" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A command is run in the background if `&` -- rather than `;`, `&&`, or a newline -- is used as the command separator that follows it.

Thus, you can start your first backgrounded process with a `&` after it, and then a subsequent sleep with a `;`, `&&`, or newline:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Start child1 in the background and child2 in the foreground after a 2m delay" >&2
./child1 & child1_pid=$!
sleep 2m  # note that "2m" is an extension; sleep 120 will work on more systems
./child2; child2_retval=$?

echo "Child2 exited with status $child2_retval"
wait "$child1_pid"; child1_retval=$?
echo "Child1 exited with status $child1_retval"
```

Comment: thanks for the details again, what is the significance of `wait "$child1_pid"; child1_retval=$?` does it waits until this process is finished grabs the status code and prints since  it runs in background ?

Comment: Exactly. By default, you lose the exit status of a background process, but using `wait` you can retrieve that status.